# Session returning null - next-auth 4.22.3

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next.js and have set up a proxy to handle API requests. I'm employing Next-auth for authentication in my application. When I make GET and DELETE requests, everything works fine. However, when I attempt to make PUT or POST requests, I get an 'unauthorized' error. It appears that the session returns 'null' during these requests and, as a result, I can't access the token to pass it forward. Has anyone encountered a similar issue and knows how to resolve it?

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req: req });
  console.log({session})

  const config = {
    method: method.toLowerCase(),
    url: url,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: sData ? sData : null,
    transformResponse: trataContent
  };

  const result = await axios(config)
    .then(tratarResult)
    .catch(tratarError);

  res.status(200).send(result);
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: Use the getServerSession instead of getSession, that's how I resolved the issue.
Check out the link for more details: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#unstable_getserversession